# Maven calling plugin from command line in parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

My project sturcture:

```html
- something-parent
-- something-one
-- something-two
```

`something-parent -> pom.xml`:

```html
<packaging>pom</packaging>
    
<modules>
    <module>something-one</module>
    <module>something-two</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.github.something</groupId>
            <artifactId>something-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now I want to execute `mvn something:help`, but I can't: `No plugin found for prefix 'something'`.

If I remove `modules` section - it works. It also works in other modules.

It just doesn't work in parent module with `modules` section. I couldn't find any documentation or literally anything describing this, is this intended? Is there any workaround?

I know `io.github.something:something-maven-plugin:1.0.0:help` will work, but I need the shortcut version to work.

//Edit1 - I know about `settings.xml` solution, but it requires manual edit by user, I would like something on a project level

//Edit2 - found out another quirk, it works when I do `mvn something:help -N`

Comment: The right to handle that is the `settings.xml` via pluginGroups (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups) ... Apart from that why do you need that often a plugin call manually? Why is that plugin not bound to the life cycle?

Comment: I know about `settings.xml` solution, but it would require telling everyone to edit it, I was hoping for something that could be done on a project level.

Comment: Plugin will have utility steps to print some info for users etc., kinda like some CLI tool, that's why manual calls would be nice.

Comment: Why do you need such utility steps? Why are such things not integrated into the life cycle... to omit such manual calls... I know how to use a. plugin and what can be done... ...

Comment: But `help` is a perfect example of such step, why would I integrate it into lifecycle? Or a popular `mvn spring-boot:run` (I have similar case here). Or `mvn spring-cloud-contract:run`. These are made to be manually called.

Comment: Help will usually not called hundrets of times ... neither spring-boot:run... I would use my IDE for such things... only as an exception on the command line ... apart from that i would use `java -jar target/xxy.jar ...` instead ... Technically you can call any goal within the lifecycle but not everything which can be done should be done w...also the correct ways have been shown .... if you give more detailed/concrete use cases it's hard.. to even guess...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to use a short name to refer the plugin when calling it from the command line.
To do that, you have to define a plugin group in your settings.xml, as of https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#plugin-groups
In your case it would be:

```
<pluginGroups>
   <pluginGroup>io.github.something</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

This allows you to call:

```
mvn something:goal
```